# jQuery hover function fails in specific case

Tags: javascript, jquery, popover

I have the following function:

```
$('[data-toggle=popover]').hover(
  function () {
   $(this).popover('show');
   }, function () {
    $(this).popover('hide');
    }
);
```

It works on this link (displays popover):

```
<p class="pull-right" style="margin-top: .5em;">
<i class="fa fa-question-circle fa-2x" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title="Export Sets Help" data-content="foo">&nbsp;</i>
</p>
```

but not this one (nothing fires):

```
<span class="green" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" title=""
data-content="foo" data-original-title="Status Detail">
<i class="fa fa-check">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>Success
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The later link was created via a datatable row so the function actions were not attached.  Adding the function to fnDrawCallback worked.